# How to get multiple rows in a flex displayed container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div id='panelB'>
<div class='card'></div>
<div class='card'></div>
<div class='card'></div>
<div class='card'></div>
</div>

#panelB{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;

}
.card{
    width:32%;
}
```

Because `card` is 32% width I expect three elements in a row, and the fourth one in a new row.

What I see is all the four `card` elements on the same row and each less then 32% width.

How to get multiple rows in a flex displayed container keeping declared width of children?

Answer (score 0):

You need two additional css declarations: flex-wrap and flex-basis. Flex-basis replaces the width.

```
#panelB {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    flex-basis:32%;
}
```

see the demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GHfal